# Invoke API of another application which has form authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application hosted in on premise IIS which has form authentication. `<system.web>` setting is:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" verbs="OPTIONS"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

So, when a user is not authenticated, it redirects to login page. My login controller looks like:
[image]

It has an API which is POST method and returns a list.

[image]

I am accessing this api using ajax in the UI.
[image: ajax call javascript]

It is working fine in this application. Now I have another MVC application which is in azure cloud and it needs to access this API.
When I am invoking it (http://my-premise-application.com/api/customer/list), it is returning the content of the login page.
What are possible way to invoke api of the first application from the second application? Any suggestion or guidance would be helpful.

Comment: You want to hit your API from other MVC project via the javascript you shared. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @G.Dimov,  I want to hit via C# code

Comment: Can you change the authentication of the on Prem system? If not you will need to have the c# app follow the login process.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments you have to make a C# HTTP call to the other project Web API. You can do it by creating anywhere in your project a class named `MakeRequestService` and one `static` method named `MakeWebRequest`, which will return a string, being the JSON you need.

```cs
public class MakeRequestService
{
    public static string MakeWebRequest(string url, string verb, int timeout, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null, string contentType = "", string json = "")
    {
        string myResult = string.Empty;
    
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            myRequest.Method = verb;
            myRequest.Timeout = timeout;
    
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
                myRequest.ContentType = contentType;
    
            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    if (header.Key == HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString())
                        myRequest.Accept = header.Value;
                    else
                        myRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }
    
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                myRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
    
            using (HttpWebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                myResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                if (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse response)
                {                
                    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream: stream);
                    myResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    stream.Position = 0;                
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myResult = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    
        return myResult;
    }
}
```

You can then use this method in the following way:

```cs
string res = MakeRequestService.MakeWebRequest(
    url: "The FULL URL of the first project, based on your example, e.g. http://localhost:69963/api/customer",
    verb: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
    );

var outcome = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Customer>>(res);
```

The `catch` block in the `MakeWebRequest` method is just an example and will return a plain string containing the JSON error body in case of an unsuccessful API call. You can modify it for your needs, e.g. rethrow the `WebException` and handle it the way you want.

The `MakeWebRequest` method is very abstract so you can use it for the API calls as well. If you make a `POST` request with JSON body - just pass the body to the `json` parameter.  If you make a `GET` request with query parameters, just build the whole URL, containing the query parameters, and then invoke the method.

Comment: Where is the login portion?

Comment: as seen in the question, the method does not require authorization

Comment: "So, when a user is not authenticated, it redirects to login page" The web.config requires authenticated users.

Comment: "Now I have another MVC application which is in azure cloud and it needs to access this API."

Comment: I believe, the API is part of the Forms auth MVC app.

Comment: The way I understood it is that he needs access only to the API part of the first project via the second project.

Comment: @G.Dimov, It redirects me to the login page that needs to handle.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't `string res` containing the desired response JSON? Or you mean after the call you have to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use to login with a C# app. You will need to modify to work with your application. The SharedCookie will need to be added to each future request since it has your Session Cookie included.

```
    public void Login()
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        string data;
        SharedCookie = new CookieContainer();

        var url = Host + "/login";
        
        try
        {
            //Start Session
            var request = CreateRequest(url, "GET");
            request.CookieContainer = SharedCookie;

            using (var tmpResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                DoWriteResponse(tmpResponse);
                tmpResponse.Close();
            }

            //Login
            
            data = "username=user&password=pass";
            bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            request = CreateRequest(url, "POST");
            request.CookieContainer = SharedCookie;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            using (var tmpResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                DoWriteResponse(tmpResponse);
                tmpResponse.Close();
            }
            IsLoggedIn = true;
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Web Error:" + ex.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Url:" + url);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Url:" + url);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DoWriteResponse(WebResponse tmpResponse)
    {
        if (debug)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("************BEGIN**************");
            Console.WriteLine("************" + tmpResponse.ResponseUri + "**************");
            Console.WriteLine("*******************************");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(tmpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var pageText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(pageText);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("*************END***************");
        }
    }

    private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string method)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Referer = Host;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36";
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

        return request;
    }
```